# Idiomatic prefetching in a streaming library

Tags: haskell, concurrency, stream, conduit, haskell-pipes

I'm working with the [streaming](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/streaming) library but would accept an answer using pipes or conduit.

Say I have

```
import Streaming (Stream, Of)
import qualified Streaming.Prelude as S

streamChunks :: Int -> Stream (Of Thing) IO ()
streamChunks lastID = do
  flip fix 0 $ \go thingID ->
    unless (thingID > lastID) $ do
      thing <- highLatencyGet thingID
      S.yield thing
      go (thingID+1)
```

To reduce latency I'd like to fork `highLatencyGet` to retrieve the next `Thing` in parallel with processing the previous `Thing` in the consumer.

Obviously I could transform my function above creating a new `MVar` and forking the next batch before calling `yield`, etc.

But I want to know if there is an idiomatic (composable) way to do this, such that it could be packaged in a library and could be used on arbitrary IO `Stream`s. Ideally we could configure the prefetch value as well, like:

```
prefetching :: Int -> Stream (Of a) IO () -> Stream (Of a) IO ()
```

Comment: How much control do you want over the total number of outstanding high-latency requests? Probably it's easy to implement `Stream (Of a) IO () -> Stream (Of (Async a)) IO ()`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This solution uses *pipes* but it could be easily adapted to use *streaming*. To be precise, it requires the *pipes*, *pipes-concurrency* and *async* packages.

It doesn't work in a "direct" style. Instead of simply transforming the `Producer`, it also takes a "folding function" that consumes a `Producer`. This continuation-passing style is necessary for setting up and tearing down the concurrency mechanism.

```
import Pipes
import Pipes.Concurrent (spawn',bounded,fromInput,toOutput,atomically)
import Control.Concurrent.Async (Concurrently(..))
import Control.Exception (finally)

prefetching :: Int -> Producer a IO () -> (Producer a IO () -> IO r) -> IO r
prefetching bufsize source foldfunc = do
    (outbox,inbox,seal) <- spawn' (bounded bufsize)
    let cutcord effect = effect `finally` atomically seal
    runConcurrently $
        Concurrently (cutcord (runEffect (source >-> toOutput outbox)))
        *>
        Concurrently (cutcord (foldfunc (fromInput inbox)))
```

The output of the original producer is redirected to a bounded queue. At the same time, we apply the producer-folding function to a producer that reads from the queue.

Whenever each of the concurrent actions completes, we take care to promptly close the channel to avoid leaving the other side hanging.

Comment: Thanks, it does look like pipes-concurrency is made for this sort of task. This isn't the type I was hoping for though